Is it possible to get analytic solution of this integral?
I am trying to evaluate the following integral, but Integrate just returns the input:
Integrate[2 E^(2 t) ExpIntegralEi[-2 t] Log[E^(-t)/t], {t, 0, x}]


Is it possible to find the analytic solution of this integral with Mathematica?

Mathematica simplify can't integrate it. So most likely this is not integarable. btw. Your e^(2t) should be Exp[2*t] You start with indefinite integration, then you see it can't solve it. No need to start with definite integration. It is because you have Exp[2*t] in front. If you remove this term, then it can do it.  https://i.sstatic.net/9QiM5CGK.png

my function have to include the e^(2t) terms, then it should be not integrable? Now I have to use this integral function to calculate, but mathematica said that this integral function cannot be used as a function in the calculation, how can I fix it?

@Nasser Mathematica is able to compute certain definite integrals although it can not compute its indefinite variant.

Another way:
Integrate[
 2 E^(2 t) ExpIntegralEi[-2 t] Log[E^(-t)/t] // PowerExpand,
 {t, 0, x}, Assumptions -> x > 0]



Assumptions -> x > t > 0 makes no logical sense, it should be Assumptions -> x > 0.

Good trick with PowerExpand Will remove my answer using numerical integration as Mathematica can do it analytically.

@azerbajdzan You may find sometimes that x > t > 0 performs better than just x > 0. It may not make logical sense to you, but I have observed it to make a difference in what the internal code produces. And I have observed adding it does not always yield the simplification it should. Further, the edge cases change with each version update, naturally. It may be eventually in some version, it won't make a difference; but I think it should, since the path from 0 to x may be complex, even if x is real. I pass these remarks along as a trick one might try when x > 0 is insufficient.

@MichaelE2 Do you have an example when x > 0 fails but x > t > 0 is successful?

@MichaelE2 I don't know why I can't get the output that you shown

@azerbajdzan Nope. Specific examples have not stuck in my memory and such edge cases have not come up very often. There may be some on site among the 750+ answers I've given that involve Integrate. Further, what made a difference in, say, V8 no longer made a difference perhaps in V10 or later. x > t > 0 is just a way to make available the assumption that the path of integration is real. The person who might know is Daniel Lichtblau. Maybe it has become part of the internal code, and over the next few years I will realize that it hasn't helped. Or not.

@miles I'm using V14.1 for Mac ARM. Integrate[]'s abilities changes often between versions.

@azerbajdzan In a similar vein, adding a redundant assumption in a different form to Simplify or Reduce sometimes helps, because, I suppose, they don't always derive and apply all the possible conclusions from the givens.

Very nice (+1). To be careful you could call PowerExpand[_, Assumptions -> 0 < t < x] to prevent blind collapsing of powers, etc. In this case it's equivalent to your call though.

Mathematica is able to evaluate it for small integers x=1, x=2, ...
By substituting such small integers for x you can guess the formula of the integral for general x.
int=(-(EulerGamma*(1 + 2*EulerGamma)) + 2*x - 
  8*x*HypergeometricPFQ[{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2}, 2*x] - 
  2*Log[2]^2 - Log[4]*Log[x] - Log[2*x] - 
  E^(2*x)*ExpIntegralEi[-2*x]*(-1 + 2*x + Log[x^2]) + 
  ExpIntegralEi[2*x]*(2*EulerGamma + Log[4*x^2]) - 
  EulerGamma*Log[16*x^2] + 
  Derivative[2, 0, 0][Hypergeometric1F1][0, 1, 0] - 
  Derivative[2, 0, 0][Hypergeometric1F1][0, 1, 2*x])/2

Which can be verified by numeric integration.
NIntegrate[
 2 E^(2 t) ExpIntegralEi[-2 t] Log[E^-t/t], {t, 0, Pi + Sqrt[2]}]
N[int /. x -> Pi + Sqrt[2]]


1.69802

1.69802


It should be noted that your formula is valid only for $x>0$.

I do not expect OP wants x<0 as he/she surely can confirm.
